# node.js call function inside function class object

Tags: node.js

i have very good js background but i am new to node.js
i dont undersand why simple class object function is not calling

```
    function functions () {

        function test () {
            console.log("function ok");

            function test2 () {
                console.log("function inside function is ok");
            }
            return {
                test2 : test2
            };  
        }

        return {
            test : test
        };

    }

var test_function = new functions();
functions.test.test2();
```

i get error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'test2' of undefined
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `test_function.test().test2()`. You need to invoke `test()` before you can invoke `test2()`. Also, in your example you correctly invoked `functions()` and assigned it to `test_function`, but then you did not do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this:

```
var test_function = new functions();
test_function.test().test2();
```